# Winsorize data in Pandas for Python

Tags: python, regression, pandas

I am trying to run a Winsorized regression in `pandas` for Python.  The [very helpful user manual](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/stats.html#standard-ols-regression) offers this example code:

```py
winz = rets.copy()
std_1year = rolling_std(rets, 250, min_periods=20)
cap_level = 3 * np.sign(winz) * std_1year
winz[np.abs(winz) > 3 * std_1year] = cap_level
winz_model = ols(y=winz['AAPL'], x=winz.ix[:, ['GOOG']],window=250)
```

The fourth line looks wrong to me: shouldn't the RHS be `cap_level[np.abs(winz) > 3 * std_1year]`?

Thanks for the help!  I'm still new to using the Pandas dataframe and want to make sure I'm understanding right.

Comment: Hi @piRSquared - I have a problem with winsorizing data in python. I have posted a question recently - can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: sorry, misunderstood the question!

You're correct that this would be wrong for most types; however `pandas.DataFrame` has special support for setting values using a Boolean mask; it will select the corresponding values from the RHS with the corresponding time value.  Under the hood it's using [`np.putmask`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html).

You can check this for yourself:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 10).reshape(5, 2))
>>> df[df > 0.5] = -df
>>> df
          0         1
0  0.000000  0.111111
1  0.222222  0.333333
2  0.444444 -0.555556
3 -0.666667 -0.777778
4 -0.888889 -1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks.  My worry is that in the original code, the first N values of cap_level will be taken and used, where N is the number of True values in the Boolean mask.  But we want the corresponding values of cap_level, not just the first N values.  The original code doesn't give the corresponding values, does it?

Comment: @DavidM Corrected my answer, please take another look.